# How do I continue a smooth stroke around a corner in zBrush?

Tags: zbrush

I have been trying to create a series of smooth lines down the outside of a bell shape, around the lip, and then back up the inside. The problem is that I can't seem to accomplish this in a single brush stroke, and every time I've tried to join up multiple strokes, the join always looks really obvious.

[image]

Is there any way to "pause" a stroke so that you can rotate your view, and then resume it smoothly? Or is there any other way in general to go about something like this?